# Time bomb to apply change after a number of days

Tags: excel, vba, date

I found code on the Internet to put a time bomb in an Excel spreadsheet.

It has a option to set number of days, like 30 or 60 or 90:

```
Private Const C_NUM_DAYS_UNTIL_EXPIRATION = 30
```

It then uses this plus today's date to calculate a future expiry date which is hidden on the spreadsheet.
Then, each time the spreadsheet is opened, it checks the current date against the expiry date and if it's the same or bigger, it triggers a status change in the Excel spreadsheet.

```vb
Sub TimeBombMakeReadOnly()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' TimeBombMakeReadOnly
' This procedure uses a defined name to store the expiration
' date and if the workbook has expired, makes the workbook
' read-only.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim ExpirationDate As String
Dim NameExists As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
ExpirationDate = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Names("ExpirationDate").Value, 2)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Name doesn't exist. Create it.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ExpirationDate = CStr(DateSerial(Year(Now), _
        Month(Now), Day(Now) + C_NUM_DAYS_UNTIL_EXPIRATION))
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ExpirationDate", _
        RefersTo:=Format(ExpirationDate, "short date"), _
        Visible:=False
    NameExists = False
Else
    NameExists = True
End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' If the today is past the expiration date, make the
' workbook read only. We need to Save the workbook
' to keep the newly created name intact.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If CDate(Now) >= CDate(ExpirationDate) Then
    If NameExists = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
End If

End Sub
```

The first issue is no matter the number of days I put in, it calculates 30 days for the Expiry Date.

The second is even though the expiry date is in the future, after it has been calculated and stored, it immediately see the future date as active and kicks off the status change.

I think because of the changes in Excel 365, the way the expiry date is stored and read has changed, the format is too old?

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate Date and Text:

```vb
Dim ExpirationDate As Date
Dim ExpirationText As String
Dim NameExists As Boolean

On Error Resume Next

ExpirationDate = DateValue(ThisWorkbook.Names("ExpirationText").Value)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Name doesn't exist. Create it.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ExpirationDate = DateAdd("d", C_NUM_DAYS_UNTIL_EXPIRATION, Date)
    ExpirationText = Format(ExpirationDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ExpirationText", _
        RefersTo:=ExpirationText, _
        Visible:=False
    NameExists = False
Else
    NameExists = True
End If
```

and then:

```vb
If Date >= ExpirationDate Then
    If NameExists = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
End If
```